# Working with coordinates x y

Tags: c++, function, structure, coordinates, geometry

I need to read from a file coordinates of points. The file looks like this:

x0 y0

x1 y1

....

Then find center and diameter of the smallest enclosing circle. But I stucked in the beginning. 
I don't know how to hold coordinates and decided to choose array of structures. I've read coordinates into structure. 
I'm going to make 4 conditions:

1 - There is one point and you can't find the smallest enclosing circle.

2 - There are 2 points. Now the task is to find distance between them and its center.

3 - There are 3 points.

4 - More than 3 points. Use of special algorithm

I tried to use vector. I don't know how to use my points (elements of vector) later in functions etc.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Distance
float distance(){
    return  sqrt((point[0].x * point[1].x) + (point[0].y * point[1].y));
}

struct Points
{
    float x, y;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
vector<Points> point;
Points tmp;

ifstream fin("Points.txt");

if (!fin.is_open())
    cout << "Cannot open the file \n";
else{
    while (fin >> tmp.x >> tmp.y){
        point.push_back(tmp);
        cout << tmp.x << tmp.y << endl;
    }
    fin.close();

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem, apart from limiting yourself to a fixed array size. As this is C++, you could use a `vector` or simple `list` and use `push_back` to store each of your points. Can you [edit] your question and add the function you are having problems with?

Comment: Is your problem, that you can't access your point array in your `distance` function?

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use vector.

Comment: I edited my code. The question is the same, you were right I meant `distance` function. And I don't know how to print my coordinates from vector..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would name the struct something like `Point` rather than `Points`,
since a single instance of the struct holds only one pair of x,y coordinates.

Then a suitable distance function might be something like

```
float distance(const Point& point1, const Point& point2)
{
  return  sqrt((point1.x * point2.x) + (point1.y * point2.y));
}
```

You can get the distance between any two points in your input set like this:

```
distance(point[i], point[j])
```

You might also want to measure the distances from your input points to
a point that is not in the set, such as a point where you think the center
of the circle might be. For example,

```
distance(point[i], candidate_center_of_circle)
```

If it were my code, I would likely make `Point` a class and give it a
member function for distance so that I could write something like

```
candidate_center_of_circle.distanceTo(point[i])
```

By the way, I *might* name the variable `points` rather than `point`
because it is a vector that holds multiple instances of `Point`.
If you intend to write things like `point[i]` a lot you might not like
`points[i]`, but if you are mostly going to make STL iterators over the vector
then you would have something like this:

```
for (std::vector<Point>::const_iterator it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
```